# Generate .pom file all artifacts in Maven

Tags: maven

I've a multi-module maven project. It has two multi-modules

- Parent POM.xml (packaging type: pom)
- Module1 POM.xml (packaging type: jar)
- Module2 POM.xml (packaging type: jar)

When I build the pom.xml using mvn build option, I am able to get all artifacts (parent pom, child jars).

But I want .pom file (not pom.xml) for child jars as well. Can anyone please suggest me what to do?

I tried by adding dependencies like maven release plugin in pom.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: What's a .pom file?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen .pom = `particularly obstructive modulation`

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

The `pom.xml` is renamed to `module1.pom` when installed (copied to the local repository) or deployed (copied to the repository). The `pom.xml` is not copied to `target`.